# Is it possible to add custom tab on 'Create/Edit User' page in EPiServer Admin Panel?

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I would like to have ability to set up additional properties for custom membership provider in EPiServer Admin Panel. Is it possible in EPiServer CMS 7 or not? Please, see https://www.dropbox.com/s/n6e0qgd4vbpsntf/settings.png?dl=0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. Decorate a webform's partial class with `[GuiPlugin(Area = PlugInArea.SidSettingsArea)]` and inherit from WebFormsBase.

Comment: An example of how this can be done: http://world.episerver.com/blogs/stefan-forsberg/dates/2009/5/adding-a-connected-company-field-to-an-episerver-user--a-love-story/

Comment: Thanks a lot! The article was very helpful!